# Joomla 3.0 - redirect 301 remove index.php add .html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I migrated an old joomla site to a Joomla 3.0. I changed the URLs into SEF friendly URLs and i need to redirect all old URLs (www.mysite.com/index.php/mypage) to the new one (www.mysite.com/mypage.html)
I tried to add this code at the bottom of my .htaccess but it doesn't work:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*)$ http://www.nextlog.it/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*)$ $1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "doesn't work" can't describe clearly the problem

Comment: With "doesn't work" i meant that the code is not doing anything.

Comment: @Olèp: You should post your complete `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the first rule, and if this is in your htaccess, remove the leading slash in your regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Olèp if the code doesn't do anything, ensure that you have mod_rewrite loaded (in httpd.conf), make sure your htaccess file is being read (make sure you have at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`)

Comment: I'm sure that mod_rewrite is loaded and .htaccess is read(i played a bit with the code and it showed some errors).

Comment: @Olèp Dunno then, because those rules in a blank htaccess file in a default apache test install [does exactly what you asked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gDzcu.png)

Comment: Then it's a problem related with the joomla .htaccess

Comment: @Olèp it has to be before any other rule you have in your htaccess file

Comment: That was the problem. I had your code in the bottom of the .htaccess. As i changed it on the top of it it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use com_redirect which is built in and will do permanent redirects. Over time the search engines will update their indexes to go to the new pages, then you can delete the redirect pages ... but in the meantime monitor where direct links are coming from. THose you need to leave in place until the direct links are updated.